# Routing email from a desktop email client to php?

Tags: php, email

Lets take a look at the following scenario:

I have a websitesite, site.com. One customer support tech guy has an email account on it: techguy@site.com. Customers send messages to that email, tech guy replies via that email. They are both using desktop email clients (thunderbird, outlook...).

What I know is: using php to read incoming mail from customers
What I want to know is: how to use php to read outgoing mail that the tech guy is sending from his client via smtp, imap..

This would be used for archiving conversations between techs and customers without forcing them to use some php app on the site to send emails (I want them to use desktop clients).

I dont know much about email protocols, but I have plenty of experience in php. Im guessing that the email daemon could be setup to call a php script every time it recieves an outgoing email or something like that. Is there any way that this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way how some products on the market are doing it is by requiring the user to install a plugin on his/her email client. Using this method doesn't matter what smtp server is used, the mails will be logged using the plugin.

Another way(this is just an idea) is to "force" the tech guy to use **your** smtp server so you can access the logs and see who sent mails and who is the receiver(accessing the logs using php)

Comment: In the actual scenario, he is using my smtp server, but the logs cannot be accessed since its a shared cPanel hosting. A plugin is not a bad solution, but doesnt work as transparently as I would like it to.

Comment: The plugin solution might be your best option here... Sage ACT and Microsoft Dynamics CRM are both using this system to track the conversations with the clients and it works quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to have a separate email address for logging purposes and simply keep it in the cc or bcc field for all communication between customer support and clients.

Comment: Quite right, but that would mean that I would have to rely on the tech guy to enter the logging address into the bcc field every time he sends an email, which isnt as transparent as it should be. He can sometimes forget to do it, and I need to log everything.

Answer (score 0):

since you can have php interpret the emails, the best thing to do is have a dedicated email address that gets piped to a script (i know this is easy to set up cpanel)

you have the client email support@domain.com which gets piped to the script - do what you want with it there.

then you have the script email back out to bob@domain.com with a from address as support-reply@domain.com - which is also piped to a script

when he replies to that, it goes to support-reply@domain.com which goes to a script, which in turn you would process, then forward back out to the client@google.com with a return address of support@domain.com

i think amazon uses a similar technique so that people can email each other back and forth, but they create coded email addresses and have a database to keep track of who they are going to and coming from.

Comment: Quite an interesting solution, and it would require adding the conversation ID into the subject field (automatically), so the app can keep track of where to send it. Then again, if the tech guy is the one that is sending the first email, he couldnt send it to support-reply@domain.com because the app would not know where to forward it. He would need to send it to client@google.com, which in turn, would not be logged.

Comment: i actually have a site that does this, where they both sent the emails to contact@domain.com. the subject has [msg:123] in it, so it knows the message ID, then the email addresses are kept in a database so it knows who to send it to. alternatively, you could have the email come from client_at_google.com@domain.com, then when you reply, the script receives it and decodes the recipient and forwards to client_at_google.com. this would require setting up a catchall type email address on that domain.